# How to hide div if JSON data doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, bootstrap-4

I have a local JSON file that's rendering data into a DataTable. I'm building out people's profile pages and I generated tabs (via Bootstrap) that a user can click on---i.e. clicking on the Languages tab shows that person's language skills.

I want to make it so that if a person does not have data (e.g. no Language skills), then that div's tab is hidden. I figured that a user browsing the page won't be able to see the data if there's nothing to click on.

I think I have to do something like `if no-data $("#div-tab").hide()` but I don't know how I'd fit it into my code (see below).

## JS snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import admData from '../JSON/adm.json';
import DataTable from 'datatables.net';

var moment = require('moment');

function loadAdm() {
    let admText = admData.d.results
    .filter(x => x.phv === "")
    .map(function(val) {
        return {
            "Ct": val.ct,
            "St": val.st
        }
    })
    if (!admText) $("#adm-id").hide();

    $('#adm-table').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: "Ct" },
            { data: "St" },
            ... // -------------- irrelevant info
```

#### HTML - Tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="adm-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#adm" role="tab" aria-controls="adm-aria" aria-selected="false">Adm</a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `admText` is an array, it will never be falsey, so the condition

```
if (!admText)
```

will never be true.

You should check if the array has any elements, so

```
if (!admText.length)
//stuff
```

Comment: It worked! Your answer was well-explained and simple to implement. Thank you!